# Making directory using read txt file

Tags: python, for-loop, directory, readfile, txt

I'm trying to make a directory using a read file but it not worked.

```
x= open(r'C:\Users\Fast Computer\Desktop\k.txt', 'r')
for f in x:
    path=r'C:\Users\Fast Computer\Desktop'
    n=f.readline()
    path=os.path.join(path,n)
    os.mkdir(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your file contains, but..

In your example..

Line 2 is already reading the lines from your file.

Line 4 will fail, because you are trying to run the readline() command from a string.

Also reading the lines from your file contain the newline character, so you should strip them.

Example:

```
x= open(r'C:\Users\Fast Computer\Desktop\k.txt', 'r')
for f in x:
    path=r'C:\Users\Fast Computer\Desktop'
    n=f.strip()
    path=os.path.join(path,n)
    os.mkdir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the content of your text file ?
`os.mkdir()` fails if the path requires recursive dir creation.
Use instead `os.makedirs()`